# JS RegEx to match certain patterns only

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to adapt my Javascript RegEx to match certain patterns only. The RegEx is used in the html5 `pattern` attribute to validate an input field.

I want to accept alphanumeric pattern of the following types only:

A-AAAA or BB-BBB (the intended pattern is: 1 digit before the "-", and 4 digits after the "-", or 2 digits before the "-", and 3 digits after the "-").

My current RegEx is:

```
/([\w]{1,2})(-([\w]{3,4}))/g
```

This one works, but accepts CC-CCCC as well, which is obviously a valid input pattern, but not the intended pattern. It accepts DDD-DDDD as well; valid again, but not intended.

Could you please assist adapting the pattern?

Comment: Use start and end anchors, and have your 2 patterns separated by `|`.  https://regex101.com/r/uV8gI4/1#javascript

Comment: @squint no need for anchors in `pattern` regexps.

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes, you're right. Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation based regex in `HTML5 pattern` attribute (as it has implicit anchors):

```
/(?:\w-\w{4}|\w{2}-\w{3})/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW3yM9/3)

Comment: Thank you very much. This one well solved my problem!

Comment: @torazaburo: `\b` is used for word boundary in this regex.

Comment: My question was semi-rhetorical. There is no need for word boundaries. The regexp in the `pattern` attribute is matched against the entire input.

Comment: Word boundaries are needed otherwise it will match `D-DDDD` in `DDD-DDDD`

Comment: no, because as I said, values of the `pattern` attribute have implicit anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple alternation example:

```
/^\w-\w{4}$|^\w{2}-\w{3}$/
```

Comment: Yes, but the anchors are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It might be slightly shorter to write

```
/\w(-\w|\w-)\w{3}/
```